# Сайт не загружается в Safari, но грузится во всех других браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, safari

*еще в Samsung Browser не грузится.....*

Имею в разработке сайт - вот он: http://185.68.210.3/
Получил его уже готовым, но уже тогда он не открывался в Сафари - загружается просто белая страница. Проверено на айфонах 4/5/6 и айпаде2. В Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera все грузится как положено.

В чем может быть дело? Подключены следующие скрипты практически в стандартном виде, имеется следующая meta.

```
<script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4VpGV6e8ZEFT34-AWovrUa5Mzyp00nVo" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/  html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>aCloud24</title>

<meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

- Исправьте **[ошибки исходного кода](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showoutline=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2F185.68.210.3%2F)** (валидация только главной страницы) + структуры сайта (см. внизу, секции Heading-level outline и Structural outline): нарушение последовательности элементов h.
- Удалите из исходного кода следующий блок: `<!-- Bar color Android/WP/Safari -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#59c7e5">
  <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#59c7e5">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#59c7e5">`

Comment: Спасибо за участие в моей проблеме!

Comment: Обнаружил, что пустая страница загружается из-за 'display:none;'  в style.css....body. Если убрать эту строку, то сайт перестает отображаться нормально в Хроме, но отображается в Сафари, хоть и без яваскриптов. Нет идей по этому поводу? Спасибо!